# Flip flop initial state

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

When you first turn on a flip flop like jk but with both input as 1 what will happen as there is no previous state to toggle.

Comment: You don't provide any context. But I never used 74xx series FFs without providing the system with a power-on reset signal. This was an *absolute* requirement. The 7400 series FF devices I used provide a CLR and sometimes also a SET input, which could be used with the power-on reset to ensure their state when power is applied.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior when there is no previous state to toggle depends on the specific implementation and could lead to an undefined or unpredictable initial output state.

Answer (score 2):

The power-on condition of any flip-flop is undefined. Maybe output \$Q=1\$, maybe it's \$Q=0\$. Maybe the clock will be triggered as power is applied, maybe it won't.

What happens depends on the physical implementation of the flip-flop, the rate at which power supply voltage rises, the random state of noise present, and any number of other variables at work.

Generally, if it's required that the flip-flop adopt a predictable, known, state immediately after power is applied, then measures must be taken to enforce that condition. For instance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faCYxl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this cross-coupled NOR gate implementation of the classic "set-reset" (SR) flip-flop, R1 and C1 hold the one of the NOR inputs *high* immediately following power on. Eventually, after about one millisecond, that input falls low, and stays there until the next power cycle.

This guarantees that the flip-flop's output \$Q\$ goes immediately high after power is applied (inputs R and S permitting, of course).

Without R1 and C1 present, there is no such guarantee.